# After upgrading spring from 3.x to 4.3.2, autowiring of JavaMailSender and VelocityEngine fails

Tags: java, spring

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire field: private
>   org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender
>   com.xxx.service.impl.NotificationServiceImpl.mailSender; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd"
   default-lazy-init="true">
<!-- Enable @Transactional support -->
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Enable @AspectJ support -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Activates scanning of @Service -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.service"/>

<bean id="userSecurityAdvice" class="com.xxx.service.UserSecurityAdvice"/>

<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"/>

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl" autowire="byName">
    <property name="host" value="${mail.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${mail.port}" />
    <property name="username" value="${mail.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mail.password}" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
       <props>
              <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">${mail.smtp.auth}</prop>
              <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">${mail.smtp.starttls.enable}</prop>
              <prop key="mail.from">${mail.from}</prop>
           </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configure Velocity for sending e-mail -->
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="resource.loader">class</prop>
            <prop key="class.resource.loader.class">
                org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
            </prop>
            <prop key="velocimacro.library"></prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Other dependencies:

- javax.mail - 1.4.7
- org.apache.velocity - 1.7

---

```
package com.xxx.service.impl;

@Service("notificationService")
public class NotificationServiceImpl implements NotificationService {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
}
```

All dependencies are properly added, `JavaMailSender` class is also present in spring-context-support-xxx.jar but cannot find a reason why it is not getting autowired. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the spring folder from .m2 directory. And then update your maven dependency and rebuild the project.

Comment: It was the first thing I did but didn't work out. Anyways thanks for reply